# MS Access: How do I set up thie Recordset.Filter filter?

Tags: ms-access

I have an issue that I am trying to find a solution for.

I have a table, it looks something like this:

```
@myTable
id - Number
value - Text
models - Memo
```

I also have a table that looks something like this:

```
@myModels
id - Number
model - Text
notes - Memo
```

The @myTable.models value is a concatenation of different @myModels.model strings concatenated with the '|' character. For instance, it might have ModelA|ModelB|ModelC| or only ModelA|ModelC|

I need to filter the recordset from @myTable based on which model is currently selected. Right now I have something like this:

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable"
Dim rs1 As Recordset
Set rs1 = DBO.Edit (sql)

sql = "SELECT model FROM myModels"
dim rs2 As Recordset
Set rs2 = DBO.Read (sql)

If Not rs2.BOF Then rs2.MoveFirst
While Not rs2.EOF

  If Not rs1.BOF Then rs1.MoveFirst
  While Not rs1.EOF
    Dim models() As String
    models = Split(rs1![models], "|")
    Dim model As String

    For Each model In models
      If model = rs2.model Then
      'Do some processing
      End If
    Next model

    rs1.MoveNext
  Wend

rs2.MoveNext
Wend
```

I was really hoping that I would be able to perform some type of regex on the query or in the filter, so it would possibly look something like this:

```
While Not rs2.EOF

  rs1.Filter( "Insert Regex Here" )
  If Not rs1.BOF Then rs1.MoveFirst
  While Not rs1.EOF
    ' Do Some Processing here
    rs1.MoveNext
  Wend

rs2.MoveNext
Wend
```

I guess that my main issue is that the @myModels table has ~ 1000 records and is growing, while the @myTable table has more than 30k records in it. This takes an extremely long time to loop through when trying to loop through each record that many times.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: DBO.Edit just returns a recordset with dbOpenDynaset and dbSeeChanges options, while DBO.Read just returns a recordset with dbOpenSnapshot and dbReadOnly options.

Answer (score 0):

did you try sql = "SELECT model FROM myModels where criteria"?
not sure what you mean by currently selected model but you can use tempVars to add temporary strings or whatever else you need
perhaps join in your sql?
can you specify in detail where is this model coming from and how its selected

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over records in VBA is generally slower than a single SQL query. Running through a single SQL query would be faster than multiple loops with VBA:

```
SELECT myTable.*
FROM myTable, myModels
WHERE myTable.models LIKE "%" & myModels.model & "%"
```

In VBA:

```
Dim sql As String, rs As Recordset
sql = _
      "SELECT * " & _
      "FROM myTable, myModels " & _
      "WHERE myTable.models LIKE ""*"" & myModels.model & ""*"""

Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(sql)
While Not rs.EOF
      'Some processing here
Loop
```

Admittedly, this will still be slow, because this is an outer join, and because we're using the non-optimized `LIKE` operator.

If instead of the `myTable.models` field, you can add an intermediate table:

```
@myTableModels
tableID - number
modelID - number
```

with proper relationships, the resulting query will be near-instantaneous:

```
SELECT myTable.*
FROM (myTable
INNER JOIN myTableModels
    ON myTable.id = myTableModels.tableID)
INNER JOIN myModels
    ON myTableModels.modelID = myModels.ID
```